# AJAX not working after database migration from MySQL to SQL Server ( Undefined index)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sql-server-2012

I have a huge problem at the moment, that I have been trying to solve for the last couple of days:

I'm migrating a database from **MySQL** to **MS SQL Server 2012** for an existing web application.

The data has been migrated successfully and matches the old data.

The problem is I had to edit a few SQL Statements in a PHP-Application, which is using the database.
The connection has been successfully established from the php-application to the new MS SQL Server. But when I try to send a query via ajax im always getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
> Message: Undefined index: filter_18

This is the ajax code im using:

```js
    $.ajax({
        url: global_url+"test/getTest"
        ,type: 'POST'
        ,dataType: 'json'
        ,data: {
             filter_1            : filter_1
            ,filter_2            : filter_2
            ,filter_3            : filter_3
            ,filter_4            : filter_4
            ,filter_5            : filter_5
            ,filter_6            : filter_6
            ,filter_7            : filter_7
            ,filter_8            : filter_8
            ,filter_9            : filter_9
            ,filter_10           : filter_10
            ,filter_11           : filter_11
            ,filter_12           : filter_12
            ,filter_13           : filter_13
            ,filter_14           : filter_14
            ,filter_15           : filter_15
            ,filter_16           : filter_16
            ,filter_17           : filter_17
            ,filter_18           : filter_18
        }
        ,async: true
        ,success: function(data) {
            $("#test").html(data.html);
            $("#amountofx").html("");
            if(data.amountofx_all != amountofx){
            $("#amountofx").html(data.amountofx_all +" von "+data.amountofx);
            }
            else {
                $("#amountofx").html(data.amountofx);
            }
    
            mleh = $(".x:nth-of-type(1)").height();
            $(".btn_show_x").height(mleh);
            $("#pagenr_data").html(data.pagenr);
            if (data.pagenr == "") {
                $("#pagenr_data").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#pagenr_data").show();
            }
        }
        ,error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
            alert("Fehler beim Auslesen der Maßnahme.");
            hideOverlay();
        }
        
    });
```

The PHP where the error first appears is this line here:

// Here I tried to modify the SQL Statement in ordert o only display 100 Objects per site

```
    $starting_from = $_POST['filter_18'] * CONSTANT_WITH_THE_VALUE_100 - (CONSTANT_WITH_THE_VALUE_100 - 1);
    $end_at = $_POST['filter_18'] * CONSTANT_WITH_THE_VALUE_100  - 1;
    //$fetch_next = CONSTANT_WITH_THE_VALUE_100 +1;
    $offset = $starting_from -1;
    
    if ( $_POST['filter_18'] > 1) {
        $sql_offset = " OFFSET " . $offset . "ROWS";
    } else { $sql_offset = " OFFSET 0 ROWS";}
        
        $sql_offset .= " FETCH NEXT " .CONSTANT_WITH_THE_VALUE_100. " ROWS ONLY";
```

Please keep in mind, that I didn't write this code I just had to change every single variable in this code snippet in order to post it here.

What confuses me the most, is that the application worked with the old MySQL Server and I haven't changed ANY syntax besides some SQL Statements. The error has to be in this ajax or in a config file etc. The SQL Statements work without ajax I've also checked them. The connection between the controller / models and ajax also works.

I’m Using codeigniter and jquery 3.5.1.

Update: Could it be that i have to include something like JSON.parse(data); to the AJAX statement ?

I really appreciate any help because at the moment I'm complete lost and don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just check what server is receiving. From your code it looks like filter_18 is defined.

Comment: seems like an error on the PHP side yet yu have shared js code. Please post the relevant php

Answer (score 0):

```
A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: filter_18
```

This notice will appear when a PHP array is missing. For example, you would have an array in PHP set as the following:

```
$phpArr = [
    'filter_1' => 'filter',
    'filter_2' => 'other_filter'
    .
    .
    'filter_17' => 'final_filter'
];
```

This error literally means that the `$phpArr` does not have the key (also known as the "Index") set in its definition. If you are operating with Errors on your PHP config set to throw `E_ALL`, then this will cause an exception. However, for most applications this will simply show as a warning, and PHP won't actually fail when this error is reached. As to why you are reaching it would likely be something with the data you are passing in as a loop. Your serverside code doesn't have the 18th filter, and it likely has very little to do with your recent migration.